# W. Mathematica-- Graphics--Making spheres

Tags: graphics, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I want to write a program in Wolfram Mathematica
We have two lists :

```
list1 = {Sphere[{x1}],Sphere[{x2}],Sphere[{x3}],Sphere[{x4}],Sphere[{x5}]}
list2 = {Sphere[{y1}],Sphere[{y2}],Sphere[{y3}],Sphere[{y4}],Sphere[{y5}]}
```

And I need to "draw" bonds between them by cylinders, thus we must have

```
list3={Cylinder[{x1,y1}],Cylinder[{x2,y2}],Cylinder[{x3,y3}],Cylinder[{x4,y4}],Cylinder[{x5,y5}]}
```

How can I do this automatically, using any lists: list1 and list2 of such kind?

Comment: By the way, if you have further questions about Mathematica, you might want to ask them over on the [dedicated StackExchange site for Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice example in the documentation for [GraphPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphPlot3D.html) which looks as if it does what you want to do, though not entirely in the way that you are approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what are the radii of the cylinders, I'm using the ones relative to the first list.

```
centers1 = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}};
radii1 = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
centers2 = {{1, -1, 1}, {2, -2, 2}, {3, -3, 3}};
radii2 = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3};

list1 = Sphere[Sequence @@ #] & /@ Transpose[{centers1, radii1};
list2 = Sphere[Sequence @@ #] & /@ Transpose[{centers2, radii2}];

Show[Graphics3D[{list1, list2, Cylinder[Sequence @@ #] & /@ Transpose[{Transpose[{centers1, centers2}], radii1}]}]]
```

[image: graphics3d]